# how px ,em ,% is measured in transform property of css?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

when we use em,px,% in transform (translate) property to move an element in X, Y direction in css ,then these units are measured (resolved) relative to what?How it decides how much to move in which direction?

Comment: The [measurement units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) are in relation to their default parameters. So for example if you use say `em` it's relative to the font size of the element in which it's used and so on based on spec.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 situations:

1. You are using [length values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths) (`px`, `em`, `ch`, etc) either [relative](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#relative-lengths) or [absolute](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths). In this case, nothing special when they are used with `translate`, they will get resolved the same way if they are used with any another property (you may refer to the link provided to understand how each one is resolved).
2. You are using percentage values. In the case the value will get resolved relatively to **the dimension of the element itself**. So using `translateX(X%)` means translate in the X axis by X% of the **width** while `translateY()` will logically consider the height.

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate